# How to avoid fields when deserialize the JSON response directly into a strongly typed object?

Tags: c#, json

I have a json response displayed as below. I am using datacontractserializer to serialize.

If I need only "text" and "created time"  from this Json response...how should be my DataContract looks like?

Do I need to have all these six properties in my data contract ?  and use "IgnoreDataMember" as attribute?

Also, do I need to give same name for my properties in datacontract (Ex : screenName, text as property name ?)

```
"abcDetails":[  
          {  
             "screenName":"my name",
             "text":"tweet desc",
             "createdTime":1423494304000,
             "entities":{  },
             "name":"abc",
             "id":"123"
          }]
```

Comment: Just don't declare the properties in your class you don't need. BTW: You don't need it to ask here. Just try and see.

Comment: Give it up, guys.  Think there's a language barrier here.

Comment: @CrazyPaste Yes it is c#........

Comment: lol Maybe a couple of language barriers..

Comment: @Relativity `I never asked you that you should answer me.`  Please include who can answer your question next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. You can omit properties that you do not need and `DataContractJsonSerializer` will skip over them.
2. You class's property names can differ from the JSON property names as long as you set the [`DataMemberAttribute.Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value to be the same as the name appearing in the JSON.
3. Your JSON is invalid, it is missing outer braces.  I assume that's just a copy/paste error in your question.

Thus your classes could look like:

```
[DataContract]
public class Detail
{
    [DataMember(Name="text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="createdTime")]
    public long CreatedTimeStamp { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember(Name="abcDetails")]
    public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

And to test:

```
        string json = @"
{
""abcDetails"":[  
          {  
             ""screenName"":""my name"",
             ""text"":""tweet desc"",
             ""createdTime"":1423494304000,
             ""entities"":{  },
             ""name"":""abc"",
             ""id"":""123""
          }]
}
";
        var response = DataContractJsonSerializerHelper.GetObject<RootObject>(json);
        foreach (var detail in response.Details)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Created Time: {0}; Text: \"{1}\"", detail.CreatedTimeStamp, detail.Text));
        }
```

produces the output

> Created Time: 1423494304000; Text: "tweet desc"

using the helper class:

```
public static class DataContractJsonSerializerHelper
{
    public static T GetObject<T>(string json) where T : class
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return GetObject<T>(json, serializer);
    }

    public static T GetObject<T>(string json, DataContractJsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        using (var stream = GenerateStreamFromString(json))
        {
            var obj = serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            return (T)obj;
        }
    }

    private static MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
    {
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value ?? ""));
    }
}
```